# How to set Spring Mybatis typeAlias?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, type-alias

my adminDaoMapper.xml code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper
  PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
  "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="dao.IAdminDAO">

    <sql id="id">
        <choose>
            <when test="id != null">#{id}</when>
                <otherwise>'아이디 없음'</otherwise>
        </choose>
    </sql>

    <sql id="phone_3">
        <choose>
            <when test="phone_3 != null">#{phone_3}</when>
                <otherwise>'해당번호 없음'</otherwise>
        </choose>
    </sql>

    <select id="selectOne" parameterType="String" resultType="java.util.HashMap">
        select * from member where id = #{id}
    </select>

    <select id="selectMemberAll" resultType="java.util.HashMap">
        select * from member
    </select>

    <select id="selectSearchMemberPage" parameterType="java.util.HashMap" resultType="member">
        select * from member order by idx desc limt #{start},#{end}
    </select>

    <select id="selectSearchMember" parameterType="java.util.HashMap" resultType="java.util.HashMap">
        select * from member 
            where 1 != 0
        <if test="id != null">
            or id like '%${id}%';
        </if>
        <if test="phone_3 != null">
            or phone_3 like '%${phone_3}%';
        </if>
    </select>

    <!-- 회원 카운트 -->
    <select id = "getCount" resultType="int">
        select count(*) from member
    </select>
</mapper>
```

my applicationContext.xml code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:mybatis-spring="http://mybatis.org/schema/mybatis-spring"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
        http://mybatis.org/schema/mybatis-spring http://mybatis.org/schema/mybatis-spring-1.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="service" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" id="dataSource">
        <property value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" name="driverClassName"></property>
        <property value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/rachelvf" name="url"></property>
        <property value="root" name="username"/>
        <property value="mysql" name="password"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath*:dao/mapper/*.xml"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="memberDao" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
        <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory"></property>
        <property name="mapperInterface" value="dao.IMemberDAO"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="adminDao" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
        <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory"></property>
        <property name="mapperInterface" value="dao.IAdminDAO"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

error code is

```
경고: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'adminService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private dao.IAdminDAO service.AdminService.adminDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [dao.IAdminDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'memberDao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sqlSessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse mapping resource: 'file [C:\Users\AIN\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\rachelivf\WEB-INF\classes\dao\mapper\adminDaoMapper.xml]'; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error resolving class. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'Member'.  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: Member
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'adminDao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sqlSessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse mapping resource: 'file [C:\Users\AIN\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\rachelivf\WEB-INF\classes\dao\mapper\adminDaoMapper.xml]'; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error resolving class. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'Member'.  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: Member
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
```

In my opinion, an error occurs because typeAlias ​​is not set.

If you specify typeAlias, a red line is drawn.

How do I set up typeAlias?

And if there are many models, is there a way to manage them integrally?

As a beginner in Spring, I do not know much. I need your help.

Comment: Are you sure the result type of query id **selectSearchMemberPage** is **membe**? no package?

Comment: no. There is a Member class in the Model package. @JeongjinKim

Comment: I resolved that

Comment: <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath*:dao/mapper/*.xml"></property>
    </bean>

Comment: added  <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="model"></property>